# Wieso ist "korrelieren" ein Wort, aber "relieren" nicht?

Tags: verb, etymology, single-word-request

Korrelation und Relation haben die gleiche Wortherkunft, die lateinischen Wörter "correlatio" bzw "relatio".

Korrelation hat ein Verb: "korrelieren", aber Relation hat (laut Duden.de) kein Verb "relieren". Wieso nicht?

Comment: Ich sehe nicht wie diese Frage reliert.

Comment: Grundsätzlich ist es im Deutschen erlaubt neue Wörter zu erfinden. Bleibt halt die Frage, ob sich diese auch auf breiterer Ebene durchsetzen.

Comment: Ich behaupte, dass *kor[r]* keine Vorsilbe ist, bei korrigieren sieht es nicht wirklich besser aus.

Comment: @guidot _con-_ (_co-_, _col-_, _com-_, _**cor-**_) = mit(einander), zusammen + _relatio_ = Beziehung → _cor-relatio_ → _Kor-relation_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ      Why did you delete the "ich bin massiv enttäuscht" bit out of the question.  That's what made it so funny! It's kind of a rhetorical question I'm asking I guess.

Answer (score 2):

> Korrelation hat ein Verb: "korrelieren", aber Relation hat (laut Duden.de) kein Verb "relieren". Wieso nicht?

Offenbar bestand keine Notwendigkeit eine *"eingedeutsche"* Version als Verb zu etablieren.
Es gibt bereits diverse Möglichkeiten dies im Deutschen auszudrücken [Quelle](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/relate):

- zuordnen
- Eine Beziehung zu jemandem / etwas haben
- entsprechen
- mit etwas zusammenhängen
- etc.

Warum sich eine eingedeutschte Version hätte durchsetzen sollen (zumal es nicht einmal ein lateinisches Verb wie z.B. *relare* gibt), ist völlig unklar und daher eher abwegig.

Answer (score -2):

Die Frage nach "warum nicht?" Ist nicht konstruktiv.

*-ieren* ist der Eindeutschungssuffix schlechthin, wenn es um Anglizismen geht. *Relatiert* ist das Pendant in *Zangendeutsch* (*Zwangsdeutsch* X *mit der Kneifzange*?). *Reliert* dagegen ist völlig unnötig, da *verhält, verhält sich* bereits gutes Deutsch ist.

*To relate* ist ohnehin viel seltener als *related*; daher ist *verwandt* eine ebenso dem Zangendeutsch zuzurechnende Wendung.

*Korreliert* ist nicht wirklich Deutsch, dürfte sehr junges Neu-Deutsch sein.

Comment: _"wenn es um Anglizismen geht"_ Ich bin mir nicht 100% sicher ob es wirklich um einen _Anglizismus_ geht, sondern ob, warum und wie diese Wörter vom Lateinischen eingedeutscht wurden.

Comment: Ergänzend: korrelieren wird mindestens [seit den 60ern](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=korreliert&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=50) verwendet.

Comment: @%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96 siehe [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Correlate%2C+korrelieren&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CCorrelate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BCorrelate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcorrelate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ckorrelieren%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bkorrelieren%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKorrelieren%3B%2Cc0). Französisch habe ich nicht verglichen, das Argument würde aber analog gelten.

Comment: Obwohl man entgegenhalten könnte, dass googles Bestand für Deutsch dem Englischen nicht gleichkommt.

Comment: @vectory _"@%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96"_ Das ist nicht Dein Ernst oder?? :-D

Comment: "da *verhällt*, *verhällt sich* bereits gutes Deutsch ist." Kommt das von *verhalten* oder *verhallen*?

Comment: "korellieren" ist kein Anglizismus, sondern eher ein Latinismus, und dieses Wort ist in der Mathematik sicher schon lang bekannt (vllt. > 100 Jahre?).

Comment: (1) Wodurch unterscheiden sich _konstruktive_ und _nicht konstruktive_ Fragen? (2) Wieso sprechen sie von Anglizismen, wo doch _korrelieren_ ein Latinismus ist?
(3) „relatiert [sic.] ist das pendant [sic.] ...“ – Das Pendant zu ...?
(4) Was ist _Zangendeutsch_, und was bedeutet die Wortfolge „Zwangsdeutsch X mit der Kneifzange“?
(5) Rein semantisch ist _X und Y verhalten (sich)_ schlechteres Deutsch als _X und Y relieren_.
(6) Welchen Zweck hat der Absatz über _verwandt_?
(7) _Korrelieren_ tritt seit etwa 1915, _Korrelation_ sogar seit etwa 1825 auf. Beides sind deutsche Wörter.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich (1) Auch diese Frage ist nicht konstruktiv. Die Bedeutung von *konstruktiv* steht hier erstmal außer Zusammenhang. Konstruktive Mathematik bedeutet, nicht axiomatisch von [tertium non datur](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_vom_ausgeschlossenen_Dritten) (der Regel *nicht nicht X also X*) auszugehen. Ich nutze das als Metapher. So ist *nicht konstruktiv* nicht unbedingt *destruktiv*. (2) Meine Aussage war nicht falsch, aber anmaßend. Ich halte die Ursprungssprache jedoch für weitgehend irrelevant. (3) Wenn Sie möchten (4) Zangendeutsch ist ...

Comment: ... Zangendeutsch. Dazu kann ich kaum mehr sagen. Google hilft eventuell. "a X b" bedeutet Kreuzung aus. "?" ist ein Fragezeichen. Fragezeichen? Ja, ein Zeichen, das eine Frage auszeichnet. (5) Reflexivität ist sich althergebrachtes Deutsch, nicht immer modern, aber es hält sich. (6) Die Bemerkung ist im Grunde ein Kommentar zur Mindermeinung. Versuchense doch selbst *Relation* zu deuten. (7) Ich sagte *Neu-Deutsch* sei es schon, nicht war? Ich meinte "ursprünglich" mit "wirklich", das sollte klar sein; Aber meine Meinung war nicht konstruktiv, gar destruktiv. Sei's drum.

Comment: Vgl. aber Lat. *vir-*, etwa *virtus* "5. character"; Ergo könnte ich gemeint haben "nicht charakteristisch". Oder *virus* "slime", PIE *weys- "slime; to produce, to beget". *wirklich* ob der angeblichen Wurzel mit En *working, workable* gleichzusetzen erscheint mir jedenfalls abwegig, falls das irgendwer dachte. *Potent* ist das Wort allemal; Durch meine Bemerkung würde eher der Begriff "Deutsch" abgewertet. Aber das wäre wohl nicht *wirtschaftlich*. Bitte nicht alles so *wörtlich* nehmen.

Comment: @rexkogitans ich gehe von meiner eigenen Erfahrung aus, da mir der Begriff zuerst aus dem Englischen bekannt wurde, den ich gern verwende, soweit die deutsche Wortform durch hinreichende Verwendung legitimiert zu sein scheint. Zumindest lege ich ein Aufleben des Begriffs nahe. Ein Freund von Belegen frühester Verwendung anhand Internet-Recherche bin ich sonst auch nicht; Also danke für den Hinweis. *Ver-ral-ten* ist nah genug dran um eine weitreichendere Verwandschaft zu vermuten, rein spekulativ.